# Converting hex string back to char

Tags: c#, .net, hex

I know- there are lots of topics concerning this, BUT even though I did look through a bunch of them couldn't figure the solution..
I'm converting char to hex like this:

```
char c = i;
int unicode = c;
string hex = string.Format("0x{0:x4}", unicode);
```

Question: how to convert hex to char back?

Comment: Are you asking about a hex string?

Comment: yes, I want to convert "string hex" back to char

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try:

```
hex = hex.Substring(2); // To remove leading 0x
int num = int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char cnum = (char)num;
```

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I didn't see leading "0x", my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        char c = 'あ';
        int unicode = c;
        string hex = string.Format("0x{0:x4}", unicode);
        Console.WriteLine(hex);
        unicode = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        c = (char)unicode;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```