# Send command & string to COM1

Tags: c#, string, command, port

I have source code in VB and I want to convert it in C# to send command & string to COM1. What's the C# code to do this?

This code in VB6:

```
Comm1.Output = Chr$(&H5)
Comm1.Output = Chr$(&H2) + Chr$(&H10) + Chr$(&H31) + msg + Chr$(&H10) + Chr$(&H32) + msg2 + Chr$(&H3)
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem by self?

Comment: I havent seen any movement on this, did you have more questions?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few tests and a [few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400050/converting-hex-string-back-to-char), I think this would work better.

```
char char2 = (char)int.Parse("2", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char char3 = (char)int.Parse("3", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char char5 = (char)int.Parse("2", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char char10 = (char)int.Parse("10", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char char31 = (char)int.Parse("31", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
char char32 = (char)int.Parse("32", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

Comm1.Write(char5);
Comm1.Write(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}", char2, char10, char31, msg, char10, char32, msg2, char3));
```

There is no mention of how you initialize the serial port, my assumption is that is already correct.  If not, there are [articles to read on the subject.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.aspx)